# Callback function syntax in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, callback

I am attempting pass a function to another function and then have the passed function executed passing to it a variable.

Here is my code:

```
func showStandardPrompt(prompt:String,view: UIViewController,numberInput: Bool, callback: (()->(String))?) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Input Data", message: prompt, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        if numberInput {
            textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
        }
    }

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
        let field = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        callback?(field.text!)
    }

    alert.addAction(OKAction)
    let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(CancelAction)
    view.presentViewController(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The error I get is in

```
callback?(field.text!)
```

The error is "Cannot convert value type of 'String' to expected argument type '()'.  I know it's a matter of syntax - just don't know what it should be.

Comment: Please try to indent your code properly, because it's difficult to understand otherwise. I fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Rob's answer is correct, though I'd like to share an example of a simple working callback / completion handler, you can download an example project below and experiment with the `getBoolValue`'s input.

### Swift 5:

```
func getBoolValue(number : Int, completion: (Bool)->()) {
    if number > 5 {
        completion(true)
    } else {
        completion(false)
    }
}

getBoolValue(number: 2) { (result) -> () in
    // do stuff with the result
    print(result)
}
```

**Important to understand:**

```
(String)->() // takes a String returns void
()->(String) // takes void returns a String
```

Comment: That is not a playground.

Comment: @PriceRingo thanks, I thought I uploaded a playground. It was a while ago

Comment: `completion(result: number>5)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the example.  That' exactly what I needed to make my project work!  And, for me, this is so much better than the old way of UIAlertView where I had to set a tag and then check the button index and tag in the delegate method.

Comment: Not a problem. This exact example is what made callbacks clear to me.

Comment: Great, just what I need, in swift 4 the changes are a little bit different:  in the parameters should be `func getBoolValue(number : Int, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool)->()) {...}`  and  to set value should be  `completion(true)` . I hope this clarification will be useful to you.

Comment: this gonna be *Function types cannot have argument labels; use '_' before 'result' *error

Answer (score 25):

I use this way :

ViewController1

```
destination.callback = { (id) -> Void in
            print("callback")
            print(id)
        }
```

ViewController2

```
var callback: ((_ id: Int) -> Void)?
callback?(example_id)
```

Answer (score 16):

try below code updated for Swift 3

```
func getBoolValue(number : Int, completion: (Bool)->()) {
    if number > 5 {
        completion(true)
    } else {
        completion(false)
    }
}

getBoolValue(number : 8, completion:{ result in
    print(result)
})
```

Answer (score 7):

You've declared `callback` to take no arguments, and then you're trying to pass it an argument.

You specified type `(()->(String))?`, which is an optional function that takes no arguments and returns a `String`.

Perhaps you mean to specify `((String)->())?`, which is an optional function that takes a `String` and returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In the parameters for `showStandardPrompt`, you declare `callback` to have the type `()->(String)`, which is a function which takes no parameters and returns a `String`.

You then call it with `field.text!` as a parameter, which obviously conflicts with the previously given type.

You need to correct the type given to `callback` to take a `String` argument and return nothing:

```
(String)->()
```