# call/execute collection view reload when an sort option is selected from drop down

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've view controller class in that i've collection view, search bar and drop down button. Drop down button is a(Ex:- @IBOutlet weak var dropDownMenuTwo: DropMenuButton!) DropMenuButton class. DropMenuButton.swift (Ex:- class DropMenuButton: UIButton, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{}) class contains tableview view in that i'm showing all sorting technquies. If i select any sorting from drop down button i will get tableview indexpath.row value in didselectitematindexpath. I want to update collection in viewcontroller immediately how is it possible. Plese help me.
[image]    Drop down is a subclass of DropMenuButton class. When value changes in this class i want to update collection reload in viewcontroller how can i handle this.

[image]

Comment: collectionview.reloaddata in didselectrow at indexpath.

Comment: didselectrow is on other empty swift file of UIbuttion.   Class is ---->DropMenuButton.swift   and inside of this class is Like  ---> class DropMenuButton: UIButton, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {  Here all tableview methods are implemented }. Collection view is implemented on other view controller class. i want to reload Here in tableview didselect how it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to do so. 
 1. You can add delegate from 'TableViewdidSelect' class to collection view implementation class. (How to add  [Delegates in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift)?)
 2. Other way is to add 'Callback'. (How to add [Callback function syntax in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290564/callback-function-syntax-in-swift)?)

Comment: One is View controller in that (**@IBOutlet weak var dropDownMenuTwo: DropMenuButton! **)   and Other one is a class of type UIButton like (**class DropMenuButton: UIButton, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{  Here tableview methods are implemented}**) this is another swift file (**DropMenuButton.swift**). When i select any sort it will update in didselectrow method there i need to reload collection view present in viewcontroller please let me know how can i achieve it thanks.