# How to pass return parameters or function from iOS dynamic framework to parent app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, sdk, frameworks

I just created dynamic framework in swift. I integrated in my other app. I am able to redirect from app to dynamic framework view. In that performed some task like call API and get response with parameters. In failure response, I show popup Alert and click on Ok button Alert closure return to previous or parent app with return parameters.

How can I solve this problem?

I used `.xib` with Swift 4.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pass the framework a callback to call when things go wrong?  Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290564/callback-function-syntax-in-swift)?

Comment: kind of @trojanfoe my doubt is if I instantiate  to app from SDK but every time I dont know storyboard identifier then how I use instantiation for navigation .Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying.  Make it so the app initializes the framework and part of that initialization is passing a callback to use in case of asynchronous errors.  You can make the app/framework relation work how you like it.

Comment: for reusability I build dynamic framework but I stuck In three point 1.How to navigate to other app from dynamic framework 2.How to pass parameters while navigation 3.And this task perform on ok alert action closure .

Comment: Can I use delegate and protocol for that ..Is it proper way ? but every time I need to add protocol on app view controller.

Comment: Your questions are too general, but you can probably use a delegate, yes.